# Search txt and csv files for string using Excel VBA without opening files

Tags: excel, vba, find, command-prompt, wscript.shell

I have a text file that is automatically generated from a machine. The machine writes the txt file in "chunks" (sorry I don't know the exact terminology). I need to pull data from this txt file, but I need the txt file to be finished before pulling data from it. I found a solution to verify that the machine has finished writing to the file... It is not as elegant as i had hoped, but seems to do the trick. Excel VBA opens a command prompt, the command prompt uses a Find command to find the string "End of Report"... This is basically one of the last lines of the txt file and pretty safe to assume the txt file is finished after this is found. This code runs in a loop 1000 times, every 10 seconds, until it finds this string or reaches 1000 tries...

The issue is that "result" returns some other characters besides just "End of Report" this is further complicated by the fact that I am attempting to run this on some csv files too... and "result" returns some additional characters also, but different from the ones returned from the txt files. For example, if I check the length of "result"... The length comes back as 43 on one file and 48 on another file... I think it is counting the file path + "End of Report" + a few more characters?

Anyways, I don't really need the "result"... I really only need a "true" / "false" if "Find" found "End of Report" or not... How can I accomplish this? Is there a different better way to do this? I am not familiar with command prompt programming.

Note: It is important that I search these files without opening them.

```
Sub test()

    Dim SearchStr As String
    Dim cmdLine As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = "D:\test2.txt"

    SearchStr = """End of Report"""

    Set cmdLine = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    result = cmdLine.Exec("%comspec% /C Find " & SearchStr & " " & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34)).STDOut.ReadAll

    Debug.Print (result)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really an expert in command line, but what I would do is export the result of the FIND command to a file, like [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-save-command-output-file-using-command-prompt-or-powershell)

Then I would check in your VBA code how many rows are in the file (either clean the file before, or check the number of rows before the export is done).

If the number of rows meets the criteria (probably 2 or more rows instead of 1), then you can set the flag to True.

Comment: I have stumbled across an "errorlevel" command that returns 0 / 1 upon success / failure of the "find" command... Can i use this somehow? having a heck of a time figuring out how to even use this?